# Assigning a variable name to a function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, variadic-functions, dice

So I'm writing a program that, once finished, will have a user roll 2 dice and then keep a running sum of the values shown and assign some points to the values that are rolled, but I am running into a problem when first getting started. 
This is what I have so far:

```
def diceOne():
    import random
    a = 1
    b = 6
    diceOne = (random.randint(a, b))

def diceTwo():
    import random
    a = 1
    b = 6
    diceTwo = (random.randint(a, b))

def greeting():
    option = input('Enter Y if you would like to roll the dice: ')
    if option == 'Y':
        diceOne()
        diceTwo()
        print('you have rolled a: ' , diceOne, 'and a' , diceTwo)



greeting()
```

(after, I plan to do calculations like `diceTwo + diceOne` and do all the other stuff - i know this is very rough)

But when it runs, it does not give nice integer values as expect, it returns `function diceOne at 0x105605730> and a <function diceTwo at 0x100562e18>` 
Does anyone know how to get around this while still being able to assign variable names in order to later be able to perform calculations?

Comment: Creating variables with the same name as a function is a bad programming practice.

Comment: Because you're referencing the functions, not the values they returned (which you just completely ignored). Also your two functions are identical, so *why do you have two functions?* You should have something more like `rollOne = dice()` and `rollTwo = dice()`.

Comment: The variables only exist within the context where they are created, in your case the variables only exist inside the function, so if you print diceOne from outside the function this will be seen as a function. Your code seems ridiculously silly to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. I'll post this as an answer because it's more readable than a comment

1. Only import random once, not in every method
2. diceOne() and diceTwo() do the same thing, so just define one method `dice()`
3. return a value from `dice()`, not assign `dice()` to `random.randint()`
4. You can call `dice()` directly in your print statement

   ```
   import random

   def dice():
     a = 1
     b = 6
     return random.randint(a, b)

   def greeting():
     option = input('Enter Y if you would like to roll the dice: ')
     if option == 'Y':
       print('you have rolled a ' , dice(), 'and a ', dice())

   greeting()
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I understand where I went wrong now!

Answer (score -1):

You have to `return` something from your functions for them to have an influence on anything outside of the functions themselves. Then, in your function `greeting()` you have to `call` the functions by calling `diceOne()` instead of `diceOne`.

Try:

```
def diceOne():
    import random
    a = 1
    b = 6
    return (random.randint(a, b))

def diceTwo():
    import random
    a = 1
    b = 6
    return (random.randint(a, b))

def greeting():
    option = input('Enter Y if you would like to roll the dice: ')
    if option == 'Y':
        diceOne()
        diceTwo()
        print('you have rolled a: ' , diceOne(), 'and a' , diceTwo())

greeting()
```

Comment: copied directly over from my text editor where it works just fine.

Comment: nevermind you are right. it got messed up. Thanks, I didnt even notice.